# How to plot GEV distribution curve using shape, location and scale parameters in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

We have calculated GEV parameters - shape, location and scale using R for a given dataset. The same parameters were used to plot the GEV curve using matlab by somebody else in the past - the result was published like this:

[image]

I need to plot the GEV curve using matplotlib - however the calculated shape, location and scale parameters are not producing the same curve - is there anything I may be missing? Possibly I might be calculating `y` incorrectly as `y` only ranges between 0 and 1 whereas original data ranges between 20 and 55.

**PARAMS CALCULATED IN R** (just for info - no need to review R code)

```
library(extRemes)
library(boot)
dataset <- read.table("table.csv")
GEVfit <- fevd(dataset$MAXTEMP,type = "GEV", method = "MLE")
```

**PLOTTING WITH PYTHON**

```
from scipy.stats import genextreme
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape = -0.168374
loc = 25.649717
scale = 2.37303

x = np.linspace(2, 11000, 100000)
y = genextreme.cdf(x, shape, loc, scale)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] your question to also include the R code you used

Comment: It has nothing to do with R code as shape, location and scale parameters are calculated at the end of the day which are the same parameter values as in the first plot.

Comment: I have added R code just in case - but thought it was less relevant

Comment: I wanted the R code to see how you made the plot. I now realize you didn't make the original. So, the thing you need to understand is, It wasn't by plotting a CDF, which only outputs values in [0, 1], which you saw when you plotted a CDF in python.  Can you add a mathematical description of what you expect to plot? You don't describe it well. If you want to plot the GEV CDF, it won't take values in [20, 55], because the codomain of a CDF is [0, 1]. If you want to plot something taking values in [20, 55], we need to know what it is.

Comment: Also, [scipy uses the opposite sign for the shape parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html), so heads up, you'll need to change the sign of `shape`

Comment: Could you share the data? Thanks

Comment: @duckmayr - the data is maximum annual air temperature every year - blue dots are observed data - the model predicts maximum air temperature in 10,000 years. I only need to plot this data and thought CDF may be the way - but I could be wrong - should I calculate `y` in another way? I found out about shape not being negative in scipy - but result was still rubbish when taken absolute shape value...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have proper fit, especially concerning `scale` and `shape` parameters.

**R** is using negative shape, while in scipy shape parameter `c` must be non-negative, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html#scipy.stats.genextreme) for details.

Your scale parameter is way too small, you have to have it in thousands, if not more, after all your X axis is up to 10<sup>4</sup>. F.e., if I run modified code with positive shape and large scale, I'll get something like figure below

```
from scipy.stats import genextreme
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape = 0.168374
scale = 2000.0
loc = 2.37303

x = np.linspace(1, 11000, 100000)
y = 20 + (55-20)*genextreme.cdf(x, shape, loc, scale)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

which, of course, is not right, but looks a lot closer to the original. Moral of the story - check your fit and/or your data

Comment: Thanks a lot, observed data are darker blue dots in the original plot. As you can see the latest data is in year 30. Quite strangely, your code produces the same shape as in my question - not like yours (only 0-1 is swapped with 20-55). Is it the right way to use CDF?

Comment: Ah sorry, just realised that you have changed scale from 2.37303 to 2000...

Comment: @Curtis Yes, scale cannot be small, you'll get vertical line on the graph for small scale.  You could play with my code and get curve close to what you want